# Algolia filtering not working

Tags: php, algolia

I have a search index with the following settings:

```
$index->setSettings([
    'searchableAttributes' => ['title', 'datePublished'],
    'attributesForFacetting' => ['filterOnly(tags)']
]);
```

I add objects to the index like so:

```
$index->addObject([
    'objectID' => $object->getId(),
    'title' => $object->getTitle(),
    'tags' => $object->getTags(), // i.e. ['tag one (special)', 'tag two', 'tag three']
    'datePublished' => $object->getDatePublished()->getTimestamp()
]);
```

I then conduct a search to get related items like so:

```
$index->search(
    [
        'filters' => $tags, // i.e. "tags:tag one (special)" OR "tags:tag two"
        'hitsPerPage' => 12
    ]
);
```

However, this always returns 0 results, even though there are multiple records with the tags being searched for. I verified this in the Algolia dashboard. So what am I doing wrong here and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Everything you're doing seems to be correct. The only issue is coming from the way you are escaping the filters in the final `search()` call.

Your `$tags` variable should be `{"filters": "tags:'tag one (special)' OR tags:'tag two'"}`.

The `filters` key should always be a string, with each filter delimited by `OR`/`AND`. When the value is a single word, you don't need any quotes, but if it has several words, you need to enclose them in `'`.

Comment: But they are enclosed, I just used double quotes instead of single quotes. I tried adding the quotes around each tag including the term 'tag:' like `"tags:tag one (special)"` and I tried just the tag text like `tag:"tag one (special)"`. Both didn't work.

Comment: Quotes should be around the value only, not including the `tag:` part. Also, it should be `tags`, not `tag` in your example. I tried on my side and it was working. If it still does not work, could you send an email to support@algolia.com including your APPID and giving us access to reading your data so we can check in a real situation?

Comment: `tag:` is a typo. I used "tags" in my code. I feel like I tried everything. What's annoying me the most is that there are no error messages so I have no idea what is actually wrong.

Comment: Could you send an email to support@algolia.com? I think we'll need to have a look at your index configuration and data to find what is wrong.